# Raphael RPG/Sidescroller Game movement

Tags: javascript, raphael

From what I understand, when I want to move an object, on the screen, I can use the .animate function to move it to where I want, e.g.

```
R = Raphael( ... );
c = R.circle( ... );
c.animate( ... );
```

would move the circle as specified in my arguments to c.animate( .. ).

However, if I want to translate almost all of my objects, (think, Pokemon on Gameboy or classic Mario platformer, where when the player moves, the player sprite actually stays put, and the rest of the world moves instead), how would it be done? Is the only way to do this by moving every object or by calling .clear() and drawing everything from scratch? There has to be a better way right?

Comment: Technically, everything *except* Mario moves when you press 'Right' in Mario, correct?  This sounds like a feasible solution.  You could create a `R.set()` for every object in the `world` and transform that set of objects.  For 3D APIs (like OpenGL), you would use a **Viewpoint Transformation**, but I don't believe any such library is supported for Raphael.